# How to link two docker containers which are spawned with two different docker-compose.yml

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I have two containers. Each one is spawned in two different docker-compose. How can I link between these containers.

Example: in a single docker-compose

```
  input:
  build: InputBuffer
  links:    
    - queue
    - output
  ports:
    - "30005:30005/udp"
```

But in the links part, I want to link to another container which is spawned by another docker-compose.yml in the same host.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `external_links`. From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/yml/#external-links):

> Link to containers started outside this docker-compose.yml or even
> outside of Compose, especially for containers that provide shared or
> common services.

Comment: Thank you, I guess this feature is added recently.